# issue with implementing a boundary for js-mindmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to implement a hard boundary for my js-mindmap by kenneth kufluk.
The map is right now movng all over the page.. in the menu area and the nodes can be dragged to any point outside the page width and height.

I want the diagram to bounce around or restrict only inside my fixed canvas size.

How do I do this?
Thanks
Priyank